# Way to determine if a sequence is geometric without common ratio

Tags: arithmetic, geometric-series

Say I have the numbers 2, 4, 8, 16. I want to find out a way to determine if this sequence is geometric without checking if 4/2=8/4=16/8. Is there are a formula that exists that would help with this?

Comment: This is the simplest and the best way to find, why do you want to complicate it ~

Comment: Another (probably harder) approach would be to take logarithms and see whether you have an arithmetic sequence

Answer (score 2):

As this is more or less the definition of a geometric sequence there is no other way to check it. Small variation are possible though as you could take the ratio of $4/2=2$ and then multiply it by each term to see if you get the next term given. This avoids repeated division but is essentially the same method, brute force.